# How to use errors in highland.js map

Tags: javascript, highland.js

This function

```
var _ = require('highland');
var accounts = ['ack', 'bar', 'foo'];

_(accounts).map(function (x) {
  return new Error(x);
}).errors(function (err, push) {
  push(null, 'fark');
}).each(function (x) {
  console.log(x);
});
```

logs

```
[Error: ack]
[Error: bar]
[Error: foo]
```

I expected it to log

```
fark
fark
fark
```

How do I use errors correctly in highland.js?

Answer (score 2):

Reading the source of the `map` function linked on http://highlandjs.org/#map you can see that the function is applied like this :

```
var fnVal, fnErr;
try {
   fnVal = f(x);
} catch (e) {
    fnErr = e;
}
push(fnErr, fnVal);
```

so if you want to transform a value into a highland StreamError via the `map` transformer, you need to throw the error.

The following code :

```
var _ = require('highland');
var accounts = ['ack', 'bar', 'foo'];

_(accounts).map(function (x) {
  throw new Error(x);
}).errors(function (err, push) {
  push(null, 'fark');
}).each(function (x) {
  console.log(x);
});
```

will give you the expected

```
fark
fark
fark
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://highlandjs.org/) you have this :

```
getDocument.errors(function (err, push) {
    if (err.statusCode === 404) {
        // not found, return empty doc
        push(null, {});
    }
    else {
        // otherwise, re-throw the error
        push(err);
    }
});
```

So I think your error still at the following line :

```
push(null, 'fark');
```

try with

```
push(err);
```

Hope this help you !

Comment: I was actually trying to recreate the `if` statement, where it gets an error and pushes a different value instead of propagating the error itself. I'm still pretty shaky on how errors work in general in this library.